# How to ensure writing 4 bytes to binary file

Tags: c, binary, fwrite, hexdump, xxd

I want to program an EEPROM which is 16/32 bit. I am writing the file from a C program, but `fwrite()` seems to be doing only 8 bits? I wrote a simple example, and using xxd (and hexdump) to look at the results, but the file seems to be only 8 bits. I wonder if I'm only seeing 8 bits due to the limitations of hexdump & xxd, or if the problem is with `fwrite()`?

Anyone know how I can check that all the bits are being written to the file?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const unsigned int dataSize = 255;
unsigned long tmp[] = { 0xFFFF, 0xFFDD, 0xFDDD, 0xF000, 0x0F0F, 0x0001, 0x1010 };
  
int main() {
    const char *path = "text.bin";
    FILE *fp = fopen(path, "wb"); 
    const void *data = tmp;
 
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "fopen() failed for '%s'\n", path);
    } else {
        fwrite(data, 1, dataSize, fp);
    }
  
    return 0;
}
```

Using **xxd** I see:

```
00000000: ffff 0000 0000 0000 ddff 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000010: ddfd 0000 0000 0000 00f0 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000020: 0f0f 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000030: 1010 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000040: c005 5182 b27f 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ..Q.............
00000050: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000060: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000070: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000080: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000090: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 00    ...............
```

**EDIT**:
I'm trying to ensure there are 32 bits written to the file. The results of **xxd** are:

```
00000000: 11111111 11111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ......
```

Which show there are 16 bits for the `0xFFFF` but where are the other 16 bits? Ideally I'd like to see 16 zeros followed by 16 ones for `0xFFFF` for a 32 bit boundary.

I'm wondering if this is a problem with the **xxd** software not displaying it, rather than C not writing it.

(I realise the names and the file pointer isn't closed, it was just something I knocked up in 2 minutes to help display the problem, I picked 255 out of the air.)

Comment: The array is not 255 bytes long; you are telling the system to read out of bounds of your `tmp` array (which is anything but temporary, but that's a naming issue and tangential to the other problems).  You're invoking undefined behaviour, which is not good. You should use `fclose(fp);` after the `fwrite()`, but the system should handle that for you.

Comment: Could you please show us what you want the contents of the file to be? It's not clear

Answer (score 1):

To control the exact output in the file, you should use the exact width types from `<stdint.h>` instead of `unsigned long`, which seems to have 64 bits on your system.

The reason you do not see 16 zeroes followed by 16 ones is your target system uses little-endian representation for integer types larger than 8 bits. [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) determines the order of bytes in memory for these types.

Furthermore, you should not write 255 bytes from the `tmp` array which has a size of 28 bytes.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// data has 256 bytes
uint32_t data[64] = { 0xFFFF, 0xFFDD, 0xFDDD, 0xF000, 0x0F0F, 0x0001, 0x1010 };
  
int main() {
    const char *path = "text.bin";
    FILE *fp = fopen(path, "wb"); 
 
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "fopen() failed for '%s'\n", path);
    } else {
        size_t written = fwrite(data, 1, sizeof data, fp);
        if (written != sizeof data) {
            fprintf(stderr, "fwrite() only wrote %zu bytes\n", written);
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem: 16 bit data (2 byte) chunks are stored in 64-bit-type (8 byte) array. This explains the output.

Solution:

- Assign x byte data to "x-byte type" (use "Fixed-Width Integer Types")
- fwrite the exact number of bytes (do not guess)

Please note that 0xFFFF is 2 bytes. Assigned data is 7 * 2 = 14 bytes. "tmp" array is 7 * 8 = 56 bytes.